# How to find optimal weighting of two ratios with non-zero covariance

Tags: optimization, independence, variance, covariance, ratio

Say you had 3 independent variables - A, B, and C

with mean values and associated variances (the actual quantities are just an example):

$\mu_A=1$; $\sigma^2_A=0.01$

$\mu_B=2$; $\sigma^2_B=0.02$

$\mu_C=2$; $\sigma^2_C=0.03$

and then you construct two ratios: $R_{AB}$ and $R_{AC}$ - which should have the same mean value.

$R_{AB} = \frac{A}{B}$; $R_{AC} = \frac{A}{C}$;

with mean values and associated variances ([Formula for variance of a ratio (Wikipedia) - Section: Example formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example%20formulae)):

$\mu_{AB} = \frac{\mu_{A}}{\mu_{B}}$; $\sigma^2_{AB} = \left(\frac{\mu_{A}}{\mu_{B}}\right)^2 \left[ \left(\frac{\sigma_A}{\mu_A}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sigma_B}{\mu_B}\right)^2 \right]$

$\mu_{AC} = \frac{\mu_{A}}{\mu_{C}}$; $\sigma^2_{AC} =  \left(\frac{\mu_{A}}{\mu_{C}}\right)^2 \left[ \left(\frac{\sigma_A}{\mu_A}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sigma_C}{\mu_C}\right)^2 \right]$

how would you find a linear combination of these two ratios that has a minimum possible variance?

$R = w_0R_{AB} + w_1R_{AC}$, where $w_0+w_1=1$

I initially used the inverse-variance weighting method to find the weights: [Inverse-variance weighting (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting) but then realized I couldn't because the two ratios $R_{AB}$ and $R_{AC}$ are not independent and have a non-zero covariance due to their common numerator.